# Rails check if yield :area is defined in content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, yield

I want to do a conditional rendering at the layout level based on the actual template has defined `content_for(:an__area)`, any idea how to get this done?

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347322/yield-if-content-render-something-otherwise-rails-3/7409626#7409626) for creating a helper method to encapsulate this behaviour in Rails 3.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

`@content_for_whatever` is deprecated.
Use `content_for?` instead, like this:

```
<% if content_for?(:whatever) %>
  <div><%= yield(:whatever) %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Helper `content_for?` exists only in Rails 3. In Rails 2 you could use `@content_for_...` instance variable.

Answer (score 10):

not really necessary to create a helper method:

```
<% if @content_for_sidebar %>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <%= yield :sidebar %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

then of course in your view:

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I use this all the time to conditionally go between a one column and two column layout

Answer (score 3):

```
<%if content_for?(:content)%>
  <%= yield(:content) %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can create a helper:

```
def content_defined?(var)
  content_var_name="@content_for_#{var}"    
  !instance_variable_get(content_var_name).nil?
end
```

And use this in your layout:

```
<% if content_defined?(:an__area) %>
  <h1>An area is defined: <%= yield :an__area %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I agree @eirikir, not sure what my 6 year younger self was thinking. I'm extending & leaving my answer in for those still on Rails 2.. without the unnecessary preamble ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am going to shamelessly do a self reply as no one has answered and I have already found the answer :) 
Define this as a helper method either in application_helper.rb or anywhere you found convenient.

```
  def content_defined?(symbol)
    content_var_name="@content_for_" + 
      if symbol.kind_of? Symbol 
        symbol.to_s
      elsif symbol.kind_of? String
        symbol
      else
        raise "Parameter symbol must be string or symbol"
      end

    !instance_variable_get(content_var_name).nil?

  end
```

Comment: Heh well I like your self-reply but... Minor point, `instance_variable_defined?(content_var_name)` is a bit neater than instead of testing whether it is nil. Second bigger point, the content_for instance variable is deprecated so your solution is not future proof

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the performance implications of calling yield twice, but this will do regardless of the internal implementation of yield (@content_for_xyz is deprecated) and without any extra code or helper methods:

```
<% if yield :sidebar %>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <%= yield :sidebar %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use @view_flow and value of the content method before checking if the content is present in the view like this:

```
@view_flow.content[:header_left_or_whatever_the_name_of_your_block_is].present?
```

Recently stumbled upon it when showing all local, global and instance variables of self in the console with byebug. I’m a fan using this because it’s straight from Rails, won’t throw an error, won’t hide anything w “Rails magic”, returns a definite true or false, + only checks the content in the current context of the view being rendered.

@view_flow  is an instance attribute of ActionView::Context and because [Action View contexts are supplied to Action Controller to render a template](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionView/Context) it will be available to any view that has been rendered by Rails. Although it checks for content, the content_for block will not be yielded if it isn’t there. So it’s been my perfect solution in similar situations.